# What does this ～づくし mean?

Tags: grammar, meaning, words, suffixes

I'm reading someone's blog and I've come across this sentence. I feel as if I should know what づくし means here, but I just can't get my head around it.

> そんな分からないづくしの世界と今自分がよく知っている世界…

If someone could give an explanation of づくし or however it is naturally conjugated, that'd be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's 尽くし which means a bunch of something.

分からないづくし世界  A world of nothing but things I don't understand.